# MongoDB spatial query opposite of $geoIntersect, outside of polygon

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, spatial

Is it possible to perform a query where a point is outside a polygon?

I'm not really sure how to word my question, but I'm trying to do this with my query

I want to check if location A (Pickup) is in inside, and location B (dropoff) is outside

I thought of using `$ne` and `$not` but I get the error `"unknown top level operator: $not"`

```
    $pickupPoint = [
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => [
            floatval($this->item['longitude']),
            floatval($this->item['latitude'])
        ]
    ];
    $dropPoint = [
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => [
            floatval($this->item['longitude']),
            floatval($this->item['latitude'])
        ]
    ];

    // Is in pickup, but outside dropoff
    $pickupNotDropoff = [
        '$and' => [
            [
                'Pickup' => [
                    '$geoIntersects' => [
                        '$geometry' => $pickupPoint,
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$not' => [
                    'Dropoff' => [
                        '$geoIntersects' => [
                            '$geometry' => $dropPoint,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Sample of data

[image: sample]

Comment: Can you post please sample data? In text mode would be nice

Comment: @Valijon I've added a screenshot to my post

Comment: post please JSON text to reproduce your code